# Layout da aplicação hospedada no servidor

Tags: servidor, google-chrome, internet-explorer, amazon-aws

Quando acesso uma aplicação minha no servidor aws da amazon pelo IE ativando o modo de compatibilidade ele fica do jeito que eu espero.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu acesso pelo Chrome ele não pega o layout devido de jeito nenhum:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem uma explicação para isso ?

Arquivo do bootstrap no servidor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Local:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo se eu jogar por cima ele nao muda o formato.

Erro inteiro assim como comentei:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://52.88.183.202/Avaliacao/Content/bootstrapcss.map

Comment: ele não ta achando o arquivo do bootstrap...ele ta la sim mas ta diferente...no servidor ta como MAP file invés de Linker Address Map...eu jogo o certo emcima dele mas ele nao entende esse Linker Address Map

Comment: o erro ta completo é isso mesmo...vou tirar print dos arquivos

Comment: editei com os prints @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: É asp.net-mvc? Tá faltando um `.` antes de `css.map`, parece um problema no View, edite a pergunta e poste o código aonde chama estes `.css`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo seu comentário o problema é que aqui está assim:

```
 52.88.183.202/Avaliacao/Content/bootstrapcss.map
```

Quando deveria estar chamando assim:

```
 52.88.183.202/Avaliacao/Content/bootstrap.css.map
```

O problema é como os seus arquivos estão sendo chamado no html (provavelmente nos Views, se for asp.net-mvc)

Comment: era isso mesmo...valeu cara